# How to calculate the time difference between two time fields , with respect to the date changes

Tags: android

I want to calculate the time difference.I have three EditTexts , I want to input the times in the first two edittexts in HH:MM format. And then calculate the time difference and  the result will show on third edittext field in same format.
If the date changes, the time difference will calculate according that, i.e

If first time = 23:00 and second time = 01:00

then, the time difference = 02:00 hours

```
public class TimeCalculate extends Activity {

    private String mBlock;
    private String mBlockoff;
    private String mBlockon ;

    // String mHours, mMinutes;

    Date date1, date2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText blockoff = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blockoff);
        mBlockoff = blockoff.getText().toString();

        EditText blockon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blockon);
        mBlockon = blockon.getText().toString();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

        try {
            date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(mBlockoff);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(mBlockon);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mBlock = getDifference(date1, date2);
        EditText block = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.block);
        block.setText(mBlock.toString());

    }
public static String getDifference(Date startTime, Date endTime) {

        if (startTime == null)
            return "corrupted";
        Calendar startDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDateTime.setTime(startTime);
        Calendar endDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDateTime.setTime(endTime);
        long milliseconds1 = startDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
        long milliseconds2 = endDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
        long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
        /*int hours = (int)diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
        int minutes = (int) (diff / (60 * 1000)); minutes = minutes - 60 * hours;
        long seconds = diff / (1000); */
        //timeDiff = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(seconds);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
        Date date = new Date(diff);
        return simpleDateFormat.format(date);

    }

}
```

I executed this code ,but gives error as Source not found.I think error at getDifference method.Please give any other logic

Comment: I don't know about your error, but watch out for the `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")` and the `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM")`; you probably want `"HH:mm"`.

Answer (score 28):

Time Difference is calculated by following code:

```
long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
```

**EDIT :**

date1 and date2 are `Date` objects, if you have `EditText` then you can convert your text in to `Date` object by using following code,

```
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Make sure user insert date into edittext in this format.
     Date dateObject;

  try{
    String dob=(tx.getText().toString());
    dateObject = formatter.parse(dob);
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObject);

    }
```

Comment: what form is of date2 and date1? are they edit text.. how to compare if we have two editeText containing time. ?