# Calculate difference between two times android

Tags: java, android, date, time, simpledateformat

I am developing and android app, where I need to calculate the difference between two times.I need to calculate the time difference for 24 hrs, and also the difference between times on two days(Eg. 5pm today to 9 am tomorrow).

I have tried the below code, to calculate the difference which works only for 24 hrs,

```
String dateStart = "08:00:00";
String dateStop = "13:00:00";

//HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

try 
{
    d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
    d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

    //in milliseconds
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    Log.e("test",diffHours + " hours, ");
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172593/how-to-calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-time-fields-with-respect-to-t/11219953#11219953). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

Sir, you can make it easily in using java feature. `long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();`  Take a look in this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/) this will help you.

Comment: I have tried this link, but I am not supplying date along with the input, I need to get the time difference using only the time. I can supply am or pm values.

Comment: ok, In background set the date and pass it. As you are passing the am/pm from it you can update the second time's date to tomorrow/today. Have you got my point.

Answer (score 10):

Correct way to find proper time difference:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("22:00:59");
Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("23:00:10");

long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime(); 
if(difference<0)
{
    Date dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00:00");
    Date dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00:00");
    difference=(dateMax.getTime() -startDate.getTime() )+(endDate.getTime()-dateMin.getTime());
}
int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
int sec = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours) - (1000*60*min)) / (1000);
Log.i("log_tag","Hours: "+hours+", Mins: "+min+", Secs: "+sec);
```

Result will be: Hours: 0, Mins: 59, Secs: 11

Comment: Awesome! I really like how you dealt with changing date

Comment: Hi, How to get Seconds in the same format like hours, min ?

Comment: @Naveen Sorry for bit late, I updated answer above for calculate seconds too, hope this help you and others too.

Comment: AWESOME, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Awesome! this resolved my issue

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( 
    LocalTime.parse( "08:00:00" ) , 
    LocalTime.parse( "13:00:00" ) 
)
```

> 5

…or…

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( 
    ZonedDateTime.of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
        LocalTime.parse( "08:00:00" ) , 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    ) , 
    ZonedDateTime.of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) ,
        LocalTime.parse( "13:00:00" ) , 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    ) 
)
```

> 53

## java.time

Modern approach uses the java.time classes.

### `LocalTime`

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "08:00:00" ) ;
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "13:00:00" ) ;
```

### `Duration`

Get a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object to represent the span-of-time.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

### `ChronoUnit`

For number of hours, use [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

```
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

### Android

For Android, see the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects. See last bullets below.

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to cross days, going past midnight, you must assign dates and time zones.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;

ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
    LocalTime.parse( "08:00:00" ) , 
    z
) ;

ZonedDateTime stop = ZonedDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ) ,
    LocalTime.parse( "13:00:00" ) , 
    z
) ;

long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/DbT47J).

> 53

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this also if you are sure the 9 am is next day you can add one day and calculate the difference:

```
String string1 = "05:00:00 PM";
    Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string1);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(time1);

    String string2 = "09:00:00 AM";
    Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string2);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(time2);
    calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    Date x = calendar1.getTime();
    Date xy = calendar2.getTime();
    long diff = x.getTime() - xy.getTime();
    diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
    float diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
    System.out.println("diff hours" + diffHours);
```

Comment: nice answer,help me alot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try simple piece of code using For 24 hour time
StartTime = "10:00";
EndTime = "13:00";
here starthour=10 and end hour=13 

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtDate.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtDate1.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtTime.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtTime1.getText().toString()))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date/Time fields cannot be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        if (starthour > endhour) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Time Should Be Less Than End Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (starthour == endhour) {
            if (startmin > endmin) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Time Should Be Less Than End Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                tvalid = "True";
            }
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sucess"+(endhour-starthour)+(endmin-startmin),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tvalid = "True";
        }
    }
same for date also
```

Answer (score -2):

I worked it out this way:

```
Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string1);
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTime(time1);

Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string2);
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.setTime(time2);

if(calendar2.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 1 && calendar1.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)     {
     calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
long diff = calendar1.getTimeInMillis() - calendar2.getTimeInMillis()
```

This will help to find the difference in time round the clock.

Comment: itsn't working when i try it with from
 `13:00 PM` to `11:00 AM`