# When time difference gets calculated the values is off

Tags: java, android, time, difference

I have a timepicker for a start time and an end time. It's in Sweden so here is 24 hour clock. If I set the start time at 23:00 and the end time at 02:00 it should be 3 hours difference. But in this case its 22 hours.

I calculate the difference lite this:

```
String a =""+Math.abs(diff/(60*60*1000)%24);
String b =""+Math.abs(diff/(60*1000)%60);
```

How can this be fixed?

**UPDATE**

Here is some more code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

Date date1 = formatter.parse(str_time1);
Date date2 = formatter.parse(str_time2);

long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

String a =""+Math.abs(diff/(60*60*1000)%24);
String b =""+Math.abs(diff/(60*1000)%60);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my timepickerdialog and maybe the error start even here:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Launch Time Picker Dialog
final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
int minute) {
startworkFrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                   }
}, mHour, mMinute, true);
timePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: I'm not founding any error here. Did **startworkFrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);** outputting a right value?

Comment: I getting 0:0 if i choose the time 00:00 and that cant be right.

Comment: Btw, why you use DateFormat and Date if you can simply checking and comparing the time with simple int comparison?. Just curious.

Comment: Because I did not know that I could do that. I am a Noob you know.

Comment: Oww... didn't know that. give me some minutes to find a sample code checking value between time...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two times android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908738/calculate-difference-between-two-times-android)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the problem I had:

```
public int theTimeMachineHours(EditText a, EditText b) throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(a.getText().toString());
    Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(b.getText().toString());

    long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    if(difference<0)
    {
        Date dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00");
        Date dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00");
        difference=(dateMax.getTime() -startDate.getTime() )+(endDate.getTime()-dateMin.getTime());
    }
    int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));
    int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60));
    int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);

    return hours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
  result_time = (end_time - start_time +24) % 24;
  // +24 to avoid the result from going to negative
```

**where end_time is your ending time i.e 02:00
start_time is starting time i.e 23:00
and % is modulo operator**

Comment: This did not fix the problem. I still get strange values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using kk:mm instead HH:mm

So change the code to:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
```

Comment: No difference. I dont want AM and PM format just to make that clear if I missed to say that. Maybe the problem is when I select **23:00** and **02:00** with the timepickerdialog the value thats get set in my edittext fields are **23:0** and **02:0** its missing a zero.

Comment: @alexandermogren: could be a Locale problem. Try DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale) (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int,%20java.util.Locale))

Comment: cant I do like this? **DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm",new Locale("SE"));**

Comment: try with **new Locale("sv","SE")**

Comment: try to change kk:mm to your previous HH:mm first.