# How to compare time in android time picker?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am using 2 time pikers in my app say one for FROM-Time and second for TO-Time. Now i want to check that while setting TO-Time it should not be less than FROM-Time and it will not allow to change the time less than FROM-Time.

Comment: You should refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172593/how-to-calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-time-fields-with-respect-to-t/11219953#11219953

Comment: You need to perform this validation check on the callbacks provided by the `TimePicker`.

Comment: @Supreet If one of the responses solved your problem, you should accept an answer in order to help people who have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set onTimeSetListeners for each spinner. In onTimeSet, you will get int hour and int minute. Convert this to seconds. Then, check if the two values overlap. If they do not overlap, set the text value with for example, fromSpinner.setText("10:00 AM").

---

EDIT: adding example code. You would set the following onDateSetListener to the toTimeSpinner and a similar one to the fromTimeSpinner.

```
private OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Date date = makeDateGMT(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        if (date.after(fromTimeDate)) {
            // We can accept this as a valid toTime
            toTimeDate = date;
            // Use simpleDateFormat to format Date
            toTimeSpinner.setText(formattedDate);
        }
    }
};

private void makeDateGMT(int year, int month, int day) {
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TIME_ZONE_GMT);
    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minute);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps. Are you not saying you want to make sure that TO-Time is always > FROM-Time?

Comment: @Supreet I've added some example code. Let me know if you need me to fill in any of the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date/time you just create a new Date object.

To compare dates you use Date.compareTo():

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date now = new Date();
int difference = now.compareTo(formatter.parse(data));
```

According to the docs, difference will be:

the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

```
if (difference == 0) {
    // the dates are equal
}
else if (difference < 0) {
    // the date is before now
}
else {
    // the date is after now
}
```