# Parse createdAt compare to current time in minutes

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a news feed on my app where posts from different users show up.

What I'm trying to show on the feed item is a timestamp that represents the difference between the current time and the time that the post was created on.

I've been trying to test it, but all I get in logcat is a value of over 400000.

This is my code:

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DDD HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
                try {
                    Log.i("Parse time: " , String.valueOf(posts.getCreatedAt()));
                    Date originaldate = originalFormat.parse(posts.getCreatedAt().toString());
                    long timeMilliseconds = originaldate.getTime();
                    Log.i("Server time (s): ", String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMilliseconds)));
                    long timeMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeMilliseconds);
                    Log.i("Server time (min): ", String.valueOf(timeMinutes));
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                    Log.i("Current time (s): ", String.valueOf(seconds));
                    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds);
                    Log.i("Current time (min): ", String.valueOf(minutes));
                    long differenceMinutes = minutes - timeMinutes;
                    Log.i("Difference time (min):", String.valueOf(differenceMinutes));

                }
                catch (java.text.ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**Edit**

This is my logcat:

```
11-07 09:20:29.820 19390-19430/? I/Server time (s):: 1420617846
11-07 09:20:29.820 19390-19430/? I/Server time (min):: 23676964
11-07 09:20:29.820 19390-19430/? I/Current time (s):: 1446884429
11-07 09:20:29.820 19390-19430/? I/Current time (min):: 24114740
11-07 09:20:29.820 19390-19430/? I/Difference time (min):: 437776
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the time difference between two time fields , with respect to the date changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172593/how-to-calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-time-fields-with-respect-to-t)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using DateUtils getRelativeDateTimeString will be more useful for you?
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Comment: Any idea how I could go about using that method in my case?